# Plotting points on a map using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to plot points on a map feature on my new project, but I've run into a problem.

This is my code select code so far:

```
$latest = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `database` WHERE `id` = '887584' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 0,100") or die(mysql_error()); 
while ($lat = mysql_fetch_array($latest)) {

// Missing Part

}
```

What I'm trying to do is plot the coordinates of my map by using this array:

```
$coordinates = array (
"$lat[lat]|$lat[long]", "$lat[lat]|$lat[long]", "$lat[lat]|$lat[long]",
);
```

But I'm not sure how to repeat the coordinates from my database using the php.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$coordinates = array();

$latest = mysql_query("
    SELECT
        `lat`
        ,`long`
    FROM
        `database`
    WHERE
        `id` = '887584'
    ORDER BY
        `id` DESC
    LIMIT 0,100
") or die(mysql_error()); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($latest)) {
    $coordinates[] = implode('|', array($row['lat'], $row['long'])); // Could be
        // shortened to implode('|', $row), but if you select more fields
        // in the future it will likely break your app.
}
```

Comment: You are an absolute lifesaver! :) I'll set your answer in 7 minutes, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking for, but it looks like you're having the code more or less written out already. I think this is what you want:

```
$coordinates = array();
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `lat`, `long` FROM `database` WHERE `id` = '887584' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 0,100") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $coordinates[] = $row['lat'] . "|" . $row['long'];
}
```

By the way, if `` `database`.`id` `` is a primary key and/or unique, then you don't need the ORDER and LIMIT part of the query.

Comment: I see I was too late here, simshaun's way of doing it should work perfectly too. My part on the ORDER and LIMIT in the query still applies though.